# How to add an ACF only for parent term?

Tags: custom-field, taxonomy, advanced-custom-fields

the question here is not for the front-end, it is for the back-end. Is there any way that I can add a custom field using ACF that only displays/shows in parent term.

```
└── Category
    ├── Motherboard <-- is a Parent Term
    │   ├── Gigabyte  
    │   ├── ASUS
    │   └── AMD
    ├── Peripherals <-- is a Parent Term
    │   ├── Headsets
    │   ├── Mouse
    │   └── Keyboards
    └── Processors <-- is a Parent Term
        ├── AMD 
        └── Intel
```

So in `/wp-admin` under `Post` the `Category` menu, all of its `Parent Term` (just like the example above) can have an ACF specific only for them and those child fields will not have those ACF. Is it possible?

I'm using ACF PRO and I'm seeing this conditional logic, but this conditional logic depends on the value of a CUSTOM FIELDS, not the hierarchy of the terms.

I know that I can use the **Post Taxonomy** in **Location Rules**, but when new parent term is added, I'll need to add it also to the **Location Rules**, what I'm trying to do here is to automate it.

Answer (score -1):

in ACF, you can use "post type"

-> Is parent (has child)
-> Is child (has parent)

Assign it in addition (AND) to your actual condition